# WPF TreeView Virtualization performance with hidden items

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, virtualization

I have a `TreeView` control where I'm allowing users to filter the items of the tree based on a keyword. I have `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` on my tree and its `ItemsSource` is databound. My `TreeViewItem`'s `Visibility` is set as follows:

`<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>`

The tree performs really great when it's not filtered, but I'm seeing a big performance hit when loading a tree item that has a big number of hidden items. From what I can see in VS's Diagnostic Tools, it seems to me that My `TreeViewItem` tries to load it's invisible child items even if they are not visible and this is causing both a memory and a CPU hit with a big number of invisible items loaded. Has anyone experienced this before? Is there a way I can override the default logic of realizing the virtualized tree items so hidden items don't get loaded?

Comment: Even with virtualization, hidden elements must be processed(i.e. bounds detection for visibility). It's possible you have such a sheer number of nodes that enumeration is the bottleneck. Making the large child nodes themselves utilize virtualization should help. Also, binding `IsVisibile` to `Visibility` seems superfluous.

Comment: @KobyDuck `IsVisible` is a property of the item's viewmodel.
I do have a big number of nodes. I was hoping for a way to improve performance. The entire hierarchy uses virtualization. I think I'm not very clear on your suggestion of making child nodes use virtualization.

Comment: How many nodes are in your `TreeView`?

Comment: [`IsVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisible(v=vs.110).aspx) is also a property of `UIElement`, thus part of `TreeView` and `TreeViewItem`. My point is that based on the code you have shown, I suspect it's binding to `IsVisible` of one of your controls, and not your view model's `IsVisible`. In saying make the large child nodes themselves utilize virtualization, I mean use a custom `TreeViewItem` that itself virtualizes its child nodes. It's more of an idea than a suggestion, because creating such a control(if you can't find one) is no simple task.

Comment: @KobyDuck The built-in `TreeViewItem` does support virtualization. I have items having big number of child items loading pretty fast when all the items are visible. My tree could have +100K items total with a single item having +25K child items. The perf hit only happens when there are hidden items.
For the `IsVisible` property, it correctly reflects what I have in my VM. I didn't share the XAML of the entire control, but the DataContext of my tree items is set to my VM and reflecting this property and other properties correctly.

Comment: I wasn't aware `TreeViewItem` handled it directly. I thought `TreeView` handled it. In any case, I ran a test with 50/100/150/200k+ items trying to reproduce the scenario you described, and while loading is slow and expansion is sometimes delayed, performance is reasonable(on my machine). I noticed a marginal improvement when setting `IsVirtualizing=true` and `VirtualizationMode=Recycling` on the child nodes with a large number of children. Your bottleneck may be from data binding those hidden nodes. Profile it with most data binding removed from the nodes.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is expected.

Let's say you have 10000 items in your collection. First 5000 have `IsVisible` set to `false`. With UI virtualization enabled, containers are generated until they fill available space. So you end up with 5000 collapsed `TreeViewItem`s (they take no space) plus a couple that fill the available space. I hope you see where the problem lies.

I think your best bet is to use *Live Shaping* (available in *WPF 4.5*). The basic idea is that invisible items are filtered out from the source collection view, so that containers are not generated for those items.

In a nutshell, instead of

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
</TreeViewitem>
```

you could use the following setup:

```
<TreeView>
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Items"
                              Source="{Binding Items}"
                              Filter="Items_Filter"
                              IsLiveFilteringRequested="True"
                              xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
            <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
                <sys:String>IsVisible</sys:String>
            </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Items}" />
    </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
</TreeView>
```

and

```
private void Items_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (YourItemType)e.Item;
    e.Accepted = item.IsVisible;
}
```

You'll also have to apply same trick to `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource`.
What this does is setup a collection view that listens to changes in `IsVisible` property and re-applies the filter when necessary (if you're using *WPF* version prior to *4.5* you'll have to do it manually).

Comment: Thanks, @Grx70 ! That did definitely put me on the right track. I wasn't able to use a `CollectionViewSource` on my `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. What I ended up doing instead is adding a `CollectionView` property on my tree item's viewmodel that wraps the child items collection and binding to that instead.